# sendmail.mc to fwd all mails for a domain -> First.Last@gmail.com (MX record already set up)

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail, centos6, rhel6

I'm currently using Google Apps to forward mails addressed to recipients at my domain balkan-preferans.de (176.9.40.169) to my address First.Last@gmail.com - this is done by the following DNS-zone served by my hoster:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2012100402   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       176.9.40.169
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
www                      IN A       176.9.40.169
@                        IN MX 1    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                        IN MX 5    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                        IN MX 5    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                        IN MX 10   ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@                        IN MX 10   ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

This has worked well for the past year, but I'd like to get rid of Google Apps, because they aren't free of cost anymore and I don't use any other features of that product.

So I'd like to change the MX-records above to point to my 2 web servers - which run 24/7 anyway.

On the servers with CentOS 6 Linux I currently run sendmail (for sending logwatch mails mainly).

Could anybody please provide some hints on which macros to add to `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` so that all mail for the balkan-preferans.de is accepted and then relayed to my address First.Last@gmail.com?

Do I have to open an incoming port in iptables firewall too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to mess with sendmail.mc - just add

```
@balkan-preferans.de first.last@gmail.com
```

to the /etc/mail/virtusertable and you should be good to go.

This assumes sendmail is set up to correctly receive mail for that domain, which I'm further assuming you've ensured already.

Comment: Ok I get it - this will "rewrite" the recipients. But I actually haven't set up anything yet to receive mail for that domain (besides MX records) - where should I do it, in `sendmail.mc`?

Comment: Add the names of the "servers" you set the MX records to to /etc/sendmail/local-host-names. You may need to remove the loopback address from the active DAEMON_OPTIONS line in sendmail.mc.

Comment: Thank you and the incoming port to open in iptables is 25? And how do I test delivery/acceptance, by connecting `telnet balkan-preferans.de 25`? And why remove the loopback adress, I currently have `DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')` there.

Comment: I usually test delivery by just sendmail an email, I'm too lazy to type everything out in a telnet session. But yes, that should let you test.

Comment: You have to remove the `Addr=127.0.0.1` part from sendmail.mc, regenerate sendmail.cf and restart sendmail.

Comment: Do I have to set `VIRTUSER_DOMAIN` too?